# How to ignore null value in r and continue running the code

Tags: r, error-handling, null

```
data_preprocessing <-
  function(trx, var_names = var_names_list) {
    trx_input <- data.frame(list(BankOwner = trx$BankOwner))
    data <- trx_input %>%
      mutate(full = ifelse(BankOwner, 1, 0))
  }
```

In this code,
When BankOwner is present in the data frame in character format, it is working. When BankOwner == null without "" is giving me error. How do i solve this one. I would like to ignore when there is null in the dataset or apply the function.

Comment: Use `is.null` to test

Comment: Please read [mcve] ... then **edit your question!**

Comment: I think `NULL` is mixed up with `NA` here.

Comment: Also, right now your function does not return anything. You either have to add `data` in the end or (even better) remove `data <-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want to do if there's a missing value? It would be helpful if I could see the structure of your data. There are two main options:

#### Pretend that NA values are not missing

This is probably what you want.

```
data_preprocessing <-
  function(trx, var_names = var_names_list) {
    trx_input <- data.frame(list(BankOwner = trx$BankOwner))
    data <-
      trx_input %>%
      mutate(full = ifelse(ifelse(is.na(BankOwner), "NA", BankOwner), 1, 0))
  }
```

#### End the function early as soon as missing data is detected.

```
data_preprocessing <-
  function(trx, var_names = var_names_list) {

    if(any(is.na(BankOwner))) {
      warning("Missing data detected, terminating function")
      return()
    }

    trx_input <- data.frame(list(BankOwner = trx$BankOwner))
    data <- trx_input %>%
      mutate(full = ifelse(BankOwner, 1, 0))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `NULL` and `NA` in R. I think you mean `NA`. Assuming this, let me just take your last command within the function and turn it to

```
data <- trx_input %>%
    mutate(full = 0) %>%
    mutate(full = replace(full, BankOwner, 1)
```